# Finding all subsets of a list of strings with recursion no loop

Tags: java, list, recursion, subset, backtracking

Is it possible to find all the subsets of a string list using only recursion and no loops? Would this require multiple methods?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

*The below Solution is not suitable as it finds only a subset of the sublists, still leaving it here as it may help the author.*

This would be a solution:

```java
public void findSubsets(List<String> list, int listSize)
{
    if(listSize <= 1)
    {
        System.out.println(list.subList(0, 1));
        return;
    }

    System.out.println(list.subList(0, listSize));
    findSubsets(list, listSize - 1);

}
```

Or if you need to return the Sub Lists:

```java
public List<List<String>> findSubsets(List<String> list, int listSize, List<List<String>> subLists)
{

    if(listSize <= 1)
    {
        subLists.add(list.subList(0, 1));
        return subLists;
    }

    subLists.add(list.subList(0, listSize));
    return findSubsets(list, listSize - 1, subLists);

}
```